# selecting an element by a class name with a dot in it with Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I want to extract information out of an HTML document with Cheerio.
I cannot alter the content of the HTML file as it has an external origin.

The element I want to extract has a class name with a dot in it:

```html
<span class='prop-data.size'> the content </span>
```

If I use the class name in Cheerio as a selector, I do not get back the element.

```
$('.prop-data.size').text() <-- gives null
```

Is it possible to select an element by a class name with a dot in it in Cheerio?

Can I escape the dot or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, escape the `.`:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const html = "<span class='prop-data.size'> the content </span>";

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
console.log($(".prop-data\\.size").text()); // => the content
```

An [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#attrvalue_2) is also possible: `'[class~="prop-data.size"]'`.

Comment: Great! I only used one '\' sign. That did not work! (I did not downvote!)